# os.makedirs throws exception even though directory doesn't exist

Tags: python, sockets, ftp, mkdir

I am coding an FTP server in python using sockets for a project. I am having trouble implementing the command that creates a new directory.

My code is as follows: `path` is the name of the new directory, `self.dir` is the current working directory.

```
newDirectory = os.path.join(self.dir, path)

try:
    os.mkdir(newDirectory)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return
```

I get this error:

`[WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists`

no matter what path is entered. Furthermore, it creates the file but still throws that exception.

Comment: What is `self.dir` and `path` exactly?

Comment: As stated in my post, path is the name of the new directory. self.dir is the current working directory, same as os.getcwd()

Comment: Without more accurate information, it's not possible to answer your question.

Comment: How is my question inaccurate? Please help me to make better questions

Answer (score 1):

try this method

```
newDirectory = os.path.join(self.dir, path)

if not os.path.exists(newDirectory):
    os.makedirs(newDirectory)
```

the error occurred because it was not creating all sub directories which were leading to the last main folder.

Comment: That is working now. It seems though that the creation of the directory results in something happening to my socket and I get a ConnectionAbortedError, any idea why this is occurring?

Comment: @Alura the connection and folder creation are not related, it maybe something else. cant tell until i see the full error and the code.

Comment: I have finally managed to fix the error, I still do not know what cause it but my MKD command is finally working. Thank you for your help